# Issues With Sending POST Requests From A Shopify App To An External API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, shopify, remix.run

I'm currently developing a Shopify app using Polaris for the frontend and Next.js for the backend. My app aims to synchronize product data from Shopify to an external service (Custom API project on Nextjs, deployed on Vercel) by sending a batch of product details via POST requests.

Here's a brief overview of how my app is supposed to work:

1. I fetch a small batch of active and published products using Shopify's GraphQL API.
2. I then attempt to send this data to an external API (`https://mynextjsserver/api/document/source`) in chunks of 10 products per request.
3. The data sent includes product details along with a `source` and a `token` for authentication on the external service.

However, I'm encountering an issue where the external API, which is supposed to only accept POST requests, is somehow receiving GET requests instead. This behavior is unexpected and leads to a `405 Method Not Allowed` response from the external API.

I've thoroughly checked the server-side code (Next.js API route) to ensure it correctly handles POST requests and appropriately responds to any non-POST methods with a 405 status code. On the client side (Shopify app frontend), I'm using `fetch` to send POST requests with JSON bodies, and I've verified the request details using browser development tools.

I suspect the issue might be with how I'm triggering these POST requests from the Shopify app or possibly a misconfiguration somewhere. Below is a simplified version of the function responsible for sending the product data to the external API:

```js
function sendProductsToMyServer(products, token) {
  let promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i += 10) {
    const chunk = products.slice(i, i + 10);
    const data = {
      documentDatas: JSON.stringify(chunk),
      token,
      source: 'SHOPIFY',
    };

    const promise = fetch("https://mynextjsserver/api/document/source", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    promises.push(promise);
  }

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
      // Handle success
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle error
    });
}
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any insights on what might be causing this behavior? Any advice on troubleshooting or fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, make the inner async function and use **await** before fetch... then use let result =  await promise.json(); then check in a console

Comment: The insights to this behavior is the API isn't working as you supposedly told.  Talk to who owns the API

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a next configuration issue? If I remember right, Nextjs uses Express middleware, there are some extra steps you need to allow express to accept POST requests. See: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html